# Passenger installation failing on centos 7, please suggest on how to fix this?

Tags: ruby, puppet, centos7, passenger, centos6.5

I am trying to setup passenger to puppet master on centos7.
For that, I ran below commands.

```
sudo yum -y install httpd httpd-devel mod_ssl ruby-devel rubygems gcc gcc-c++ libcurl-devel openssl-devel
```

THen, I ran below comand:

```
sudo gem install rack passenger
ERROR:  Error installing rack:
        rack requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
        rake requires Ruby version >= 2.2.
```

But, I am getting this error.

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
```

WHat should I do now?

```
sudo yum update ruby
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
No Packages marked for Update

sudo yum update ruby-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
No Packages marked for Update
```

same issue with centos7 and centos 6.5

```
cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

cat /etc/system-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: You should install a modern (and supported) version of Puppet.  No remotely recent Puppet requires Passenger, and for quite some time, Puppet comes in a package that includes all dependencies, including Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

It seems default ruby in centos is very old. You might need to install from source. BTW, please consider using rubys manager like [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [rvm](https://rvm.io).